# For a rational number $x \in [-a/4, a/4)$ with a positive integer $a$, is it possible to separate it into its integral and fractional parts?

Tags: rational-numbers

For a rational number $x \in [-a/4, a/4)$ for a positive integer $a$, is it possible to separate it into its integral and fractional parts?
Namely, can we represent $x$ as $x = b + c$ where $b \in \mathbb{Z}_a, c \in [-1/4, 1/4)$?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{Z}_a$?

Comment: It can be either {0,1,...,a-1} or {-a/2, ...,0,...,a/2}

Answer (score 0):

We see that the interval length for $c$ is $\frac12$ so we can multiply by $2$ to get closer to the [ordinary fractional part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part) definition.
Multypliing by $2$ gives
$$-\frac{a}2\le 2x<\frac{a}2,\,\\ 2x=2b+2c,\,\\ -\frac12\le 2c <\frac12,\hbox{so}$$ $0\le 2c+\frac12<1$ and $\left\{2c+\frac12\right\}=\left\{2x+\frac12\right\}$ so we can $c=\frac12\left(\left\{2x+\frac12\right\}-\frac12\right)$ and $b=x-c$.
However, this implies $2b=\lfloor2x+\frac12\rfloor$ to be integer, not $b$ itself. Let's take some $x$ such as $2b=1$, e.g. $x=\frac12$ and there will be no such $c,-\frac14\le c<\frac14$ for $x=b+c$ for some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: What is the purpose of multiplication by 2?

Comment: See the edits $\,$

Comment: Thank you! What do you mean by that ordinary fractional part?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_part

Comment: {2c+1/2} = {2x + 1/2}...? What's the meaning of the braces here?

Comment: $\{.\}$ is the fractional part.